# Comment dire "it’s one thing to ..., (it’s) another thing to ..." en français ?

Tags: traduction

Bonjour ! En anglais, on dit souvent que "it’s one thing to ..., (it’s) another thing to ..." et je voudrais savoir comment le traduire en français. Ça a l'air trop anglophone de dire littéralement "c'est une chose de ..., et une autre de ..."

Qu'en-pensez vous ? Merci !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votre proposition est assez proche de ce que j'utilise et entends régulièrement, qui est

> **C'est une chose de** XYZ, **c'en est une autre de** ABC

cela marche aussi sous la forme

> XYZ est une chose, ABC en est une autre

ou encore

> XYZ est une chose, [mais] c'en est une autre de ABC

"C'en est une autre" est une contraction de "cela en est une autre", qui dans le contexte de cette phrase signifie "cela est une autre chose de".

Un [exemple d'utilisation](https://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/40-2/chambre/seance-18/debats) trouvé sur la Chambre des Communes Canada:

> Proposer une loi stricte **est une chose**, mais **c'en est une autre d**'avoir le leadership nécessaire afin de mettre en place une stratégie pour la faire respecter et de fournir les ressources voulues.

A noter que c'est utilisé avant un verbe ou une action, comme en Anglais finalement. Le "de" a le même rôle que le "to" Anglais qui est d'introduire l'action/le verbe que l'on va comparer à l'autre (chose).

Comment: Merci pour vos explications !

Answer (score 0):

Je dirais qu'une formulation telle que « ... c'est une chose, mais ... c'est tout autre chose » serait parfaitement compréhensible en français. Votre proposition de traduction le serait aussi.

Plus familièrement, dans le cas d'une tâche à réaliser, on pourra dire aussi « ... peut-être/pourquoi pas/d'accord/je veux bien/c'est une chose, mais ... c'est une [autre paire de manches](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/une-autre-paire-de-manches) ! »